# How to pass global variables through switch/case

Tags: swift

I realise this has been asked before, but the answer here (to declare the variable outside the block) doesn't seem to work.
[link description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959680/how-do-i-increase-the-scope-of-variables-in-switch-case-loops-in-swift)

```
  var filter: String
    func Usage() {
    print("Usage: <filter> <input> [output]")
    print("System filter paths do not need to be specified.")
    return
}

    let arguments = ["qwe", "value", "qwe", "asd"]
    print(arguments.count)
    switch arguments.count {
    case 1:
        Usage()
    case 2:
        Usage()
    case 3:
        filter = arguments[1]

    default:
        filter = arguments[1]
        print (filter)
    }
    print (filter)
```

I get "value" in Xcode's playground for the first print, but the second gives "\n" or "value not initialized".
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please update your question with enough code for people to reproduce the problem. This does not mean your whole project.

Comment: Hi benwiggy, it's not enough code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code won´t compile first of all, you do get the error `error: variable 'filter' used before being initialized`

So declare filter as follow:
`var filter = String()` or `var filter = ""`

Secondly since you´re not adding all of your code I tried the following:

```
var filter = String()
let x = 0

switch x {
case 1:
    print("1")
default:
    filter = "value"
    print(filter)
}
print(filter)
```

This prints out:

```
value
value
```

If you need further help update your question with more information.

**Update:**
Just tried your updated code:
    var filter = String()
    let arguments = ["qwe", "value", "qwe", "asd"]
    print(arguments.count)
    switch arguments.count {
    case 1:
        break
    case 2:
        break
    case 3:
        filter = arguments[1]

```
default:
    filter = arguments[1]
    print (filter)
}
print (filter)
```

And this prints out:

```
4
value
value
```

Which is exactly what it should print out. Remember the initialization of `filter`.

**Update 2:**
This is what you´re trying to do, your other result was always return 4 because that´s the count of `arguments`. Try the below code instead.

```
var filter  = String()
func Usage() {
    print("Usage: <filter> <input> [output]")
    print("System filter paths do not need to be specified.")
    return
}

let arguments = ["qwe", "value", "qwe", "asd"]
print(arguments.count)

for i in 0..<arguments.count {
    switch i {
    case 0:
        Usage()
    case 1:
        Usage()
    case 2:
        Usage()
    case 3:
        filter = arguments[1]
    default:
        filter = arguments[1]
        print (filter)
    }
}
print (filter)
```

This prints out:

```
4
Usage: <filter> <input> [output]
System filter paths do not need to be specified.
Usage: <filter> <input> [output]
System filter paths do not need to be specified.
Usage: <filter> <input> [output]
System filter paths do not need to be specified.
value
```

Comment: It seems to be when I add a function in the other case statements, it breaks. The function just prints text (at this stage).

Comment: Add the code to the function and I´ll take a look @benwiggy

Comment: @benwiggy, your code works fine but you do realize that the iteration starts with 0 and this is not included in your switch and the default will be hit.

Comment: Hmm. It still doesn't work here. Count method seems to start from 1, though.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still getting "used before initialized", so I think I'll just set fire to my code and start again.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be an entry point for a command line interface.

This is an alternative approach without declaring a global variable and without a `switch`.

`Usage` is printed if the number of arguments is less than 3 otherwise the first two arguments after the name of CLI (at index 0) are assigned to two variables.

```
let arguments = ["qwe", "value", "qwe", "asd"]
print(arguments.count)
if arguments.count < 3 { 
   Usage()
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
} 

let filter = arguments[1]
let secondArgument = arguments[2]
print (filter, secondArgument)
```

Then you could `switch` over the `filter`

```
switch filter {

  case "value": doThis(with: secondArgument)
  case "someOtherFilter": doThat(with: secondArgument)
  default: doNothing()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The arguments are going to be filenames, so I can't check for all possible types. Also the number of arguments can vary. I've done it in python; I might just see if I can get that compiled....